# What does this specific .cmd file do?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need help with this cmd file with the following content:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,4 delims= " %%a in ('dir e:\ /t:c^|findstr /i /l "v"') do echo %%a %%b
echo on
pause
```

I can't figure out what it does.

Can anybody help me?

I know the output, but I don't know why it gives me this output.

Here is the output. I didn't want to post it at first because my Windows is German, sorry:

```
 Datenträger in Laufwerk E: ist Volume
 Volumeseriennummer: 1AB8-6911

 Verzeichnis von e:\

22.09.2015  09:09                 0 282ba90118a5f80716
06.10.2015  09:07                 0 32f0961d6cc71b3c51bdc6
06.10.2015  09:07                 0 4f1ab9edc5ed58c95f344fd2bc84a6ec
02.02.2016  10:56    <DIR>          ada200fdfcff43bdf47cf363ddf8
22.09.2015  09:08    <DIR>          Besitzer
06.10.2015  09:07                 0 bf5f62260169474da0ec9df993590745
06.10.2015  09:07                 0 de9afd1afa67ed193d0adb16010b54
10.10.2016  20:29    <DIR>          ImportAfter
01.12.2006  22:37           904.704 msdia80.dll
03.10.2016  15:27    <DIR>          myxampp
08.09.2015  16:20    <DIR>          Schule
08.09.2015  16:20    <DIR>          Spiele
               6 Datei(en),        904.704 Bytes
               6 Verzeichnis(se), 865.948.643.328 Bytes frei
```

The .cmd file gives me this output:

```
Datenträger E:
Volumeseriennummer:
Verzeichnis
6 Bytes
```

But why?

Comment: It runs `dir e:\ /t:c^|findstr /i /l "v"`, extracts the 1st and 4th words from the output, assigns the first word to `%a` and the fourth word to `%b`, and prints `%a` and `%b`. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120731-00/?p=7003/

Comment: e:\ is my hard drive. But what is "/t:c^"?

Comment: I suggest to first run in a command prompt window just `dir e:\ /t:c` and look on the output. Next run `dir e:\ /t:c | findstr /i /l "v"` and compare the filtered output with the complete output of `dir` above in same command prompt window. And last run the batch file and look what it finally outputs filtered once more using `for`.

Comment: Ok i did that. So the first command gives me information about my hard drive e:/. And the second command filters the information with all lines containing a 'v'. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can read about the options of a com.and by typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explain the batch code command by command in order of execution for the line:

```
for /f "tokens=1,4 delims= " %%a in ('dir e:\ /t:c^|findstr /i /l "v"') do echo %%a %%b
```

First executed command is:

```
dir e:\ /t:c
```

This command according to help output by running in a command prompt window `dir /?` outputs the files and directories in root directory of drive E: with displaying the creation date because of `/t:c` instead of the last modification date as by default.

The files and directories are output on [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) (New Technology File System) formatted drives sorted alphabetically because NTFS does that sort which could be important here.

On FAT16, FAT32 and [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) drives the files and directories would be listed unsorted as stored in [File Allocation Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) (FAT). Therefore the usage of **DIR** parameter `/O:N` would be additionally needed to get the list sorted by name for any drive independent on file system.

The output of command **DIR** written to **STDOUT** is redirected to **STDIN** of console application **FINDSTR** for further processing using the pipe redirection operator `|`. See the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for details.

`|` should be interpreted as redirection operator on execution of

```
dir e:\ /t:c | findstr /i /l "v"
```

done by command **FOR**.

To achieve this it is necessary to escape `|` by putting `^` left of it. The command interpreter `cmd.exe` on parsing the command line interprets `|` now as literal character and not as redirection operator because of `^` before.

If just `|` would have been used instead of `^|` within the **FOR** command line the Windows command interpreter would exit the execution of the batch file on that line because of a syntax error as the redirection operator `|` would be invalid in the middle of the **FOR** command line. The error message would be on German respectively English Windows:

> English:   | was unexpected at this time.
> German: "|" ist syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitbar.

Running in a command prompt window `findstr /?` outputs the help of this standard Windows console application. The usage of `/i` makes the search case-insensitive. And `/l` tells **FINDSTR** to interpret the search string `"v"` as literal string and not as regular expression. So **FINDSTR** should output all lines containing either `V` or `v`.

For the posted output of **DIR** this means **FINDSTR** outputs:

```
 Datenträger in Laufwerk E: ist Volume
 Volumeseriennummer: 1AB8-6911
 Verzeichnis von e:\
               6 Verzeichnis(se), 865.948.643.328 Bytes frei
```

The output of command **DIR** filtered already by **FINDSTR** is next processed line by line by command **FOR**.

The **FOR** parameters `"tokens=1,4 delims= "` as explained in help output by running `for /?` in a command prompt window result in splitting up each line into several strings using the space character as separator for the strings.

The first string should be assigned to the loop variable `a` as being specified next on the **FOR** command line.

The fourth string should be assigned to next loop variable with is `b` according to [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Loop variables are case-sensitive because of this feature to assign multiple strings to multiple loop variables.

All other space delimited strings from the line are of no interest and are ignored for that reason.

This additional line filtering by command **FOR** results in the output:

```
Datenträger E:
Volumeseriennummer:
Verzeichnis
6 Bytes
```

But it is quite clear now that this output is not for what the code was designed for originally.

For that reason let us assume the **FOR** command line

- is written for an English Windows instead of a German Windows
  *(with Germany selected as country in Windows region settings which determines date/time output format as DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM)*,
- root directory of drive E: contains at least one file or directory containing `V` or `v` being of interest for the batch code writer,
- the files and directories are output sorted by name (by NTFS) and
- output is the creation date instead of last modification date.

So the command `dir e:\ /t:c` outputs:

```
 Volume in drive E is
 Volume Serial Number is 1AB8-6911

 Directory of e:\

22.09.2015  09:09                 0 282ba90118a5f80716
06.10.2015  09:07                 0 32f0961d6cc71b3c51bdc6
06.10.2015  09:07                 0 4f1ab9edc5ed58c95f344fd2bc84a6ec
02.02.2016  10:56    <DIR>          ada200fdfcff43bdf47cf363ddf8
22.09.2015  09:08    <DIR>          Besitzer
06.10.2015  09:07                 0 bf5f62260169474da0ec9df993590745
06.10.2015  09:07                 0 de9afd1afa67ed193d0adb16010b54
10.10.2016  20:29    <DIR>          ImportAfter
01.12.2006  22:37           904.704 msdia80.dll
03.10.2016  15:27    <DIR>          myxampp
08.09.2015  16:20    <DIR>          Schule
08.09.2015  16:20    <DIR>          Spiele
13.11.2016  12:53    <DIR>          VeryImportantDirectory
               6 File(s)        904.704 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  865.948.639.232 bytes frei
```

This output filtered with `findstr /i /l "v"` is:

```
 Volume in drive E is
 Volume Serial Number is 1AB8-6911
13.11.2016  12:53    <DIR>          VeryImportantDirectory
```

And those three lines are filtered next by command **FOR** which outputs:

```
Volume E
Volume is
13.11.2016 VeryImportantDirectory
```

It can be supposed that the first two lines are not really of interest and the last line is what is really of interest for the original batch code writer.

The batch code is most likely written for getting output:

**The creation date and name of all files/directories containing `v` in any case.**

Comment: Thanks for the hint on NTFS sort, I wasn't aware of it, always having set the var `DirCMD=/OGN` in the system environment. Only wishing powershell gci could that do also.